# Apache specific path 301 redirects next to TLD redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am moving a blog hosted on an Apache server to a new domain.

The permalinks are kept the same for the blog posts but there are a few pages where the url slug will change on the new domain.

My question is if the following is possible and how I would do that with rewrite rules.

1. The URL slugs/permalinks of the blog posts and most of the pages on the old domain will stay the same on the new domain. So I imagine that I could add a redirect rule that redirects from `https://huiskopenomteverhuren.nl/ to https://vastgoedmentor.com` as it will find the same /slug on the new domain
2. Some pages of the old website have moved to new permalink. So I need additional rules to redirect for example `https://huiskopenomteverhuren.nl/kennisbank/ to https://vastgoedmentor.com/resources` and do this for a few other pages as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post samples of from which URL to which URL you want to redirect/rewrite in your question for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Could you please post them into your question(not in comments please), in CODE TAGS in question we could understand it better, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)huiskopenomteverhuren\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://vastgoedmentor.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} vastgoedmentor\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/kennisbank/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ resources [L]
```